# Can i call ecommerce:send before pageview send?

Tags: google-analytics-api

i've read multiple forums and all the google documentation i could find (analytics, ecommerce, custom dimension) but i did not find the answer for this question:

Can i call `ga('ecommerce:send');` before `ga('send', 'pageview');` ?

my current (simplified) ga code setup looks like this and i'm wondering if its correct (by that i mean that it ll send just 2 tracings: 1st for pageview hit inncluding custom dimension, and 2nd for ecommerce?)

```
ga('create', '***', 'auto', {
    'allowLinker': true
});
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '***',
    'revenue': '***',
    'currency': '***'
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '***',
    'name': '***',
    'sku': '***',
    'category': '***',
    'price': '***',
    'quantity': '1'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('set', 'dimension1', '***');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work for standard Ecommerce tracking. You'll be sending 2 hits to Google Analytics, one for the transaction (e.g. ecommerce:send) and then one for the pageview.